# Is light spectrum "exactly" measured or are descriptions of light frequencies "approximative"?

Tags: optics

Is light spectrum "exactly" measured or are descriptions of light frequencies "approximative"?

That is, if we are given a picture like this:

[image: https://i.pinimg.com/600x315/29/c4/ba/29c4bafe1aa1c27cae3fab27ba0163c5.jpg]

Then **how accurate** is this?

E.g. if we read the orange at 600 nm, then is this orange really "exactly" 600 nm in wavelength?

Reasons to believe it's quite accurate:

- Light may exist as a quite precise phenomenon, e.g. through filtering.

Reasons to believe it's not quite accurate:

- What's an accurate measuring device?

Comment: This is not a measurement. It is just a plot generated on a computer.

Comment: The mesurement errors will depend on the range studied. For examplefor visible light frequencies see this https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/jpa-00221749/document . For gamma rays it is th e energy error in measuring the gamma , from E=hν. For long waves ....

Comment: @my2cts Yes but for example it says that a particular orange is 600 nm. But is it?

Comment: The green line of mercury is at 546.1 nm. And you could look up a few more decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

**There is no such thing as an exact measurement in physics.**

When you say things like

> for example it says that a particular orange is 600 nm. But is it?

the answer is not special to measurements of wavelength. Thus, as an example, if you go into a lab, pick up the most precise ruler possible, and measure the length of, say, a box, you might come up with a reading of 25.7cm. "But is it?" $-$ no, it isn't. It's 25.7cm *up to the uncertainty of the measurement*.

The same thing goes with wavelengths. The wavelength of light can be measured using a [spectrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrometer), and light can be split up into its component wavelengths using a [monochromator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochromator). Both of those instruments will have a finite resolution, that you will only ever be able to report, say, (600.000±0.001)nm. However, this wavelength resolution can (at least in principle) be made arbitrarily small, if you have enough resources (both monetary and otherwise) to spend into your instrumentation.

And, again: none of this is specific to wavelengths. The same holds with *all* physical measurements.